# IBM Mobilefirst 8.0 LTPA Based Security Check - not called handleSuccess method once token obtained

Tags: android, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-server

I try to create Cordova mobile app based on angularjs following this tutorial: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/08/11/best-practices-for-building-angularjs-apps-with-mobilefirst-foundation-8.0/
and LTPA Based Security Check login flow (in Mobilefirst 8.0) based on sample from: https://github.com/mfpdev/ldap-and-ltpa-sample

Mobile app is using angular. Authorisation implementation:

```
app.factory('Auth', function ($rootScope) {

    var securityCheckName = 'LTPA',
        _$scope = null,
        challengeHandler = null,
        URL = '',

    challengeHandler = WL.Client.createSecurityCheckChallengeHandler(securityCheckName);
    challengeHandler.securityCheckName = securityCheckName;
    WLAuthorizationManager.login(securityCheckName, {'username': '', 'password': ''});

    challengeHandler.handleChallenge = function (challenge) {
        if (challenge && challenge.loginURL) {
            URL = challenge.loginURL;
        }
    };

    challengeHandler.handleSuccess = function (data) {
        // code
    };

    challengeHandler.handleFailure = function (error) {
        // code
    };

    return {
        login: function ($scope, username, password) {
            _$scope = $scope;

            var request = new WLResourceRequest(URL, WLResourceRequest.POST);
            request.send("j_username=" + username + "&j_password=" + password + "&action=Login").then(
            function(response) {
                challengeHandler.submitChallengeAnswer({});
            },
            function(error) {
              // on error
            });
        }
    };
});
```

This seems to work only on iOS. On Android `handleSuccess` function is not invoked.

As in the past, there was a problem with sending cookies on Android devices (with older MF versions) so I tried workaround in `login` function, that the hidden InAppBrowser was opened with logon form, then a user login process was made and once token was received, it was set via `cordova-cookie-master-plugin` and `submitChallengeAnswer` was invoked:

```
login: function ($scope, username, password) {
    _$scope = $scope;

    var request = new WLResourceRequest(URL, WLResourceRequest.POST);
    request.send("j_username=" + username + "&j_password=" + password + "&action=Login").then(
    function(response) {
        if (device.platform == "iOS") {
            challengeHandler.submitChallengeAnswer({});
        } else {
            iab = cordova.InAppBrowser.open(URL, "_blank", "hidden=yes");
            iab.addEventListener('loadstop', function(event){

                iab.executeScript({code:
                    'var field1 = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[0];' +
                    'var field2 = document.getElementsByTagName("input")[1];' +
                    'field1.setAttribute("value", "' + username + '");' +
                    'field2.setAttribute("value", "' + password + '");' +
                    'document.forms[0].submit();'
                }, function(){
                    // on error
                });

                try {
                    cookieMaster.getCookieValue(URL, 'LtpaToken2', function(data) {
                        WL.Client.setCookie({
                          "name" : "LtpaToken2",
                          "value" : data.cookieValue,
                          "domain" : ".example.com",
                          "path" : "/",
                          "expires" : "Thu, 18 Dec 2999 12:00:00 UTC"
                        }).then(function() {
                            challengeHandler.submitChallengeAnswer({});
                        }).fail(function(err) {
                            // on error
                        });
                    }, function(error) {
                        // on error
                    });
                } catch(err) {
                    // on error
                }

            });

            iab.addEventListener('exit', function(){
                iab.removeEventListener('loadstop', function() { /* on success */ });
            });
        }
    },
    function(error) {
      // on error
    });
}
```

This solution also not working for me. I've expect that after  `challengeHandler.submitChallengeAnswer()` was fired, the `handleSuccess` will be invoked, but it is not happened. `handleChallenge` is invoked instead.

Comment: Why are you making a resourcerequest and then performing submitchallengeanswer() in its success callback? The resourcerequest will result in the flow entering the handlechallenge and will not enter the success callback ( where submitchallengeanswer is) until the challenge has been answered.

Comment: `login` function is invoked on click, so the flow is more like: when WLResourceRequest has been send, in the success callback submitChallengeAnswer() is performed and in the result handleChallenge(),  handleSuccess() or handleFailure() should be called. On iOS (on which it works properly) after submitChallengeAnswer(), handleSuccess() is performed and login process ends successfully, but on Android (where the problem is) handleChallenge() is performed instead.